# how to remove html tags from a dataframe in r

Tags: r, csv, dataframe, strip

I have the following data:

[image]

What I want to do is to remove the HTML tags from the description column also if there are any data like this "Ù…Ø­Ø±Ø±/Ù…Ø­Ø±Ø±Ø©" could be removed.

here is my code after removing null data.

```
mydata <- read.csv("data science - sample date.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings=c("", "NA"), sep = ",")
mydata[mydata==""] <- NA
mydata <-na.omit(mydata)
```

Comment: You'd have to parse out the markup to do it properly.  What do you want to retain?

Comment: sadly it is a CSV file I got from my customer. I want to clean the data and remove the HTML code.

Comment: A picture of data is not a reproducible example. I would try to parse the data using an HTML parsing library as regular expressions are not sufficient to parse HTML

Comment: you are right. but I already have the data as CSV format. I don't know a function in HTML library for a dataframe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do

```
df <- data.frame(x = c('my <a href="foo">bar</a> <span>rocks</span>'))
df$x <- gsub("<[^>]+>", "", df$x)
df
#              x
# 1 my bar rocks
```